# Missing yaml file in cpanel database folder and Ghost databases

Tags: json, database, yaml, cpanel

I have some ghost databases that need to be deleted in cpanel. They cannot be viewed phpmyadmin and are no longer necessary and are non-existent.

The databases are still in dbindex.db file, username.json, and dbindex.db.cache.  They are located in /var/cpanel/databases. The username.yaml file does not exist. Everything is working correctly except the non existent databases are still in these files for some reason.

Does cpanel use the username.json file to populate the database info if the yaml file is missing? Also, how can I get rid of these ghost databases, and should I recreate my username.yaml file for any reason?

I am assuming I should delete the database info for the unwanted databases from dbindex.db, username.json, and dbindex.db.cache(somehow rebuild the cache?). What should I do about the missing yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Cpanel had switched from using yaml to json at one point(I think 11.50) for the Cpanel database index.  I believe you can remove the databases from the json file and then run /usr/local/cpanel/bin/dbindex to update the index.  Just back up the files you are changing before you do any changes to them.